# What is the meaning of the phrase 'all our'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

I read a sentence recently:

> May there be sweet-sour flavour in all our lives.

What is the meaning of the phrase "*all our*"?

Does it mean "*in the lives of all of us*" or "*all through our lives*"?

Comment: shortened form of “***In all of our***”

Answer (score 1):

It means *in everyone's* life. So your first guess was the right one.